# Loader not stop after coming back to redirected website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have implemented the loader after submit the form and redirecting to third part webiste. So, when i came back from redirecting webiste by click on browser back button. then loader still show.

i have tried to set loader state false with useEffect. I also tried it by using finally methode but did not solve my problem.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const hideLoader = () => 
    {
      setLoader(false)
    };
    window.onload = hideLoader; 
    return () => {
      window.onload = null;
    }
  }, [])

  const onChangeHandle = (event) => {
    setUser(event.target.value);
  }


  const onSubmitHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoader(true);
    window.location.href = 'https://create-react-app.dev/';
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">    
    {loader && (
              <div>loader .....</div>
            )}  
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandle}>
      <input type='text' name='user_name' id='user_name' onChange={onChangeHandle} value={user} />
      <br /><br />
      <br /><br />
      <button  type='submit'>submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, I pasted your code in [a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-cookies-6290hl?file=/src/App.js) and it seems that the loader is not appearing after coming back on the page.
Just by reading your code I could tell that it's working. When you open the page again, you start rendering the component as if it was the first time. Your `loader` state will then be set to its default value, false.